# How can we add Standard Popovers Panels in Lightning Component anchor links?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-link, popover

I don't know if there is a trick to include link hovers (which we have on Lookup fields) automatically in Lightning Experience environment on a custom link created to open a lookup record.

Just like following Popover on a Contact Link:
[image]

I would like to add this kind of link information popover on an `anchor` link in a custom `Lightning Component`.

Is this possible or some great mind here have a suggestion to share? :-) ...

Comment: I don't think there is any standard component for that currently, but you can create your own popover component using [Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/#flavor-panels).

Comment: I was afraid of that but can we do dynamic reading of compact layout fields via Apex without metadata api?

Comment: You can use Salesforce [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_compact_layouts.htm).

Comment: That's equivalent of metadata api considering I'll be required to add Remote Endpoint in subscriber org as REST API is not available for use in Lightning Component (can be done via Apex class only in Lightning Cmp) .. :-(

Comment: Oh yes you're right ! I don't have another solution in mind, sorry :(

Comment: Did you ever find/build a solution for this?

Comment: Nothing yet. I am hopefull Winter 18 have some kind of input and output field component that would do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

And Use with html attribute

`onmouseenter="{!c.handleMouseEnter}" 
 onmouseleave="{!c.handleMouseLeave}"`

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/#content

Comment: The necessity is not mouseover but how to pull popover card info fields dynamically or automatically without hard coding fields in Lightning Exp.